# Visibility of StackPanel in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

> I'm working with WPF using Prism ( MVVM). I wanted to set visibililty
>   of StackPanel from ViewModel calss. The StackPanel's visibility is
>   binded like :

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="spVisibility"  Orientation="Horizontal" 
          Visibility="{Binding spVisibility, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

> I've view model class like :

```
  public class SearchId : BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private Visibility _visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

      private DelegateCommand<object> searchCommand;

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public SearchId()
      {
            searchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.SearchData);
      }///

       public Visibility spVisibility
       {
            get { return _visibility; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.Equals(_visibility, value))
                {
                    _visibility = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("spVisibility");
                }
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, 
                 new PropertyChangedEventArgs  (propertyName));
            }

        }

        private async void SearchData(object parameter)
        {
            _visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
   }
```

> But this not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_visibility = Visibility.Visible` is setting the private property instead of using the public one so `RaisePropertyChanged("spVisibility")` is being bypassed.  You need to use `spVisibility = Visibility.Visible`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM i would recommend using a Boolean value instead of Visibility. The whole purpose of MVVM is seperation of View Logic from DataLogic.

View logic:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
      Visibility="{Binding ShowStackPanel, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Use a Converter to convert the boolan to a Visibility Property.. BooleanToVisibilityConverter is part of .NET and can be referenced without defining it manually in the xaml.

```
public class SearchId : BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool _showStackPanel;

  private DelegateCommand<object> searchCommand;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public SearchByIDVM()
  {
        searchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.SearchData);
  }///

   public bool ShowStackPanel
   {
        get { return _showStackPanel; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_showStackPanel, value))
            {
                _showStackPanel= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ShowStackPanel");
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, 
             new PropertyChangedEventArgs  (propertyName));
        }

    }

    private async void SearchData(object parameter)
    {
        ShowStackPanel= true;
    }
```

}